# Flexbox alignment with images and text inside same container

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I am making a flexbox Employee ID card layout.  The employee's picture will go to the left and the employee's info (name, employee-id, department, etc) will go to the right of the image in a list format top-to-bottom.

I need to do this using flexbox.

Here is a link to my JSFiddle with what I have done so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hopped_Up_Designs/3teLbqqf

```css
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
   
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 1220px;
}
.flex-item {
  height: 120px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #e46119;
  border: 1px solid #626262;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
span {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <span>Text fields will go here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <span>Text fields will go here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <span>Text fields will go here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <span>Text fields will go here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <span>Text fields will go here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <span>Text fields will go here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <span>Text fields will go here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <span>Text fields will go here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <span>Text fields will go here</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any and all help would be much appreciated.  Thanks, Jason

Comment: "*Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code*" doesn't mean you should convert the link into code. It means you must include the code in your question. And what is the problem with your current code?

Answer (score 22):

The most unobtrusive approach which I found was to add this:

```
.flex-item {
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.flex-item img{
    flex-grow:0;
    flex-shrink:0;
}
```

If you add multiple `<span>` immediately after the img, they'll continue displaying in row fashion (like a float).  This may not be the what you want, though. One option could be to set each item to a fixed width - but that breaks the spirit of flexbox.

But if you modify your text wrapper to contain a single `<div>`, I think you'll be fine. The `<div>` will display as a block level element until you choose otherwise.

```
<div class="flex-item">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Text fields will go here</li>
      <li>and here</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Here's a fork of your fiddle where I did this. http://jsfiddle.net/Paceaux/7fcqkb50/1/

Answer (score 4):

Just wrap your info in a container set to `display: inline-block`:

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex-item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
    <div class="info-container">
       <p>Field 1</p>
       <p>Field 2</p>
       <p>Field 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.info-container{
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   padding: 0 0 0 5px;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

.info-container p{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/w5tLqucc/1/)

Comment: @JasonKeithMcCoy No problem. Glad to help. Can you please check this off as resolved when you can?